# Regular expression for a sequence of hyphenated key-value pairs

Tags: asp.net, regex, webforms

i need to validate a text box for this format of data input -

"TeSt12-12TeSt,12Test-Ab12,...."

which basically is a series of key-value (key hyphen value) split using a comma (,)

Readlike

anyAlphaNumeric followed by hyphen anyAlphaNumeric then "optional from here" comma and anyAlphaNumeric followed by hyphen anyAlphaNumeric then comma and anyAlphaNumeric followed by hyphen anyAlphaNumeric...

Here 1s can be A-Z, a-z, 0-9
Examples - 
11-11 is valid
111-111, is invalid (comma should be followed by another key-value set)
1-1,1-1 is valid
1- is invalid (value is missing after hyphen)
1-1,111-111,11-11111,111-111111 is valid

Comment: I tried this but doesn't fulfill -

([A-Za-z0-9]*?-[A-Za-z0-9]*)+

Comment: +1 for a very well written question. The specs are crystal clear, unlike most other "I need a regex"-questions.

Comment: Thanks Tim, this was my first question to any forum and I wanted to be crisp and clear!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All right:

```
^        # Start of string
\w+      # Match any alnum,
-        # hyphen,
\w+      # any alnum.
(?:      # Try to match...
 ,       # comma,
 \w+     # any alnum,
 -       # hyphen,
 \w+     # any alnum
)*       # zero or more times.
$        # Match end of string.
```

or (as a non-verbose regex):

```
^\w+-\w+(?:,\w+-\w+)*$
```

Be aware that `\w` will also match the underscore (and, in a .NET environment, may also match Unicode letters and digits. If you don't want that, use `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand a bit of the execution of regular expressions to be able to build something like this and when it comes to repetitions (specifically comma seperated lists) you need often do a little bit more. This should do the trick.

```
([^-]+-[^,]+)(,[^-]+-[^,]+)*
```

When you write regular expression you are creating a very simple parser that will consume characters from left to right in a greedy manner. This imposes certain restrictions on how you write your regex.

This snippet translates to the following.

- Match a group that starts with any number of non hypen characters followed by an actual hyphen followed by any number of non comma characters, create a group for this match
- The next group is a bit intresting because the match should only succeed if there's a comma seperating the pairs. By preceeding the second group with a comma you tell the regex engine to only continue if there's a comma there. The rest is exactly identitcal.

The reason why each character class is anything but the seperator is because the greedy regex engine would otherwise not realize that there's a decsion to be made given the current imput. Most regex problems relate to a failed understanding of the greedy nature of regex (there are lazy engines as well but they are slower and not really standard regex)

You could rewrite the pattern like this to become more practical to use:

```
(?:(?<key>[^-]+)-(?<value>[^,]+))(?:,(?<key>[^-]+)-(?<value>[^,]+))*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

or to simplify

```
[^-]+-[^,]+(,[^-]+-[^,]+)*
```

[^-] this means anything that is not "-"